# Detect MAC Addresses? - via browser, without a plugin

Tags: validation, browser, mac-address

For validation purposes, is there a way to detect a user's mac address as they're signing up on a webpage, for example? I'd prefer a LAMP approach, but also open to ASP.NET possibilities.

Comment: Wouldn't the MAC address be in the TCP stack? In that case, forget an easy PHP solution.

Comment: You need an extremely good reason to be dealing with MAC addresses on a webpage.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? And why MAC address specifically? Why not use their IP address? Or, better yet, use cookies.

Comment: The original idea is to try to use it as validation-by-device -- for a use-case where many users will be on hte same local WiFi / same IP address.

Comment: also, please don't be accept-grinches - let's make stackoverflow an ultimate knowledge repository. if you have an idea, share it. many of my questions have yet to receive a sufficient answer, but come up top on many searches in google. your solution will reach people!!!

Answer (score 8):

I guess you could by reading the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) cache of the underlying OS, assuming that the client and server are on the same network.

**However**, using the MAC address for validation is under most circumstances a **bad idea**:

- The MAC address can be easily [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing). Many network drivers allow you to set the address to whatever you want.
- The MAC address is [link local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). If there is at least one router between the server and the client, the server will see the closest routers MAC address.

Comment: I guess it appears the only way to detect the mac address is to to use a client-side plugin. The original idea is to try to use it as validation-by-device -- for a use-case where many users will be on hte same local WiFi / same IP address.

Comment: I'd suggest using regular cookie-based sessions, an SSO (or user+password) framework or client certificates. Which is best depends on your situation and environment.

Try to use a common and proven technique before re-inventing the wheel. It's well worth the effort.

Comment: Well, there's also a validation problem. One account per user - cookie-based sessions, they could just log out, and create a new account... or use a different browser.

Comment: If you plan to let users create their own accounts, you will have to accept that a single person might create several accounts. If you go down the route of identifying the web terminal you will run into cases when a person has a perfectly legitimate reason to change terminal. Take a step back and think about why unique users is important to you. How about using OpenID, http://openid.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to detect mac-addresses is not a good idea.

But you can use a Java Applet to do so. The user will have to allow it to run though.

The Java Applets can be embedded in any webpage

Here is how you do it http://techdetails.agwego.com/2008/02/11/37