# How to check Android MAC to access my page?

Tags: android, mac-address

I have a website page that I want to limit the access with MAC Address; It's ok with desktop devices, some developers from the enterprise had already done a plugin to check de mac from those devices;
Now I'm developing a mobile version and I need to check the Android Smartphone/Tablet MAC to grant access to the website

How can I do it?

Comment: You can read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278666/4117717
However you can also use nodejs and test these packages: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=Arp (i.e node-arp)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > WiFi > Menu > Advanced

I think that is just the Wifi MAC address. Not sure if the mobile network is different.

Comment: thanks, Cricket. But I need to check it on the website

Answer (score 0):

**For pre lolpop verions**

```
   WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
   String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

You also need to add permission in menifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I'll try it soon. Thanks