# Get user MAC address wirelessly

Tags: php, ip

I need to show the user their MAC once they enter a website (for now I have instructions for finding it but the system needs a revision so I thought maybe I'll make it a bit more user-friendly). It can't be an app since I have no way of knowing what kind of device a user might have.

I think it should be possible to run on a server locally and use either the router's binding list or arp to compare against an IP address, but I'm no programmer and unfortunately most sites I've visited straight up say it's impossible.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac = `arp $ip_address | cut -d " " -f4`;
echo "<br />Your Mac is: ";  
echo $mac;
?>
```

seems valid, but i don't know how to use it

EDIT2: I thought just now to explain myself better - the MAC will be used to update a router's whitelist to allow a user internet access (captive portal didn't work cause ancient hardware).

EDIT3: ARP seems the correct choice here.

Now to do: 
on a server
Check IP, check ARP table, get MAC, push to client.

on client
Ask the server upon website entry, write answer to webpage.

Comment: *"most sites I've visited straight up say it's impossible"* ... and what makes you think it isn't? (without installing some kind of browser plug-in spyware anwyay)

Comment: what makes me think it isn't is seeing the arp command and router binding table, which I mentioned in the post, there should be a way to access it somehow - and if it's on a server then code can be ran to check local connections by IP address; i'm not asking for a web-wide solution, only a local one

Comment: So: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278628/detect-mac-addresses-via-browser-without-a-plugin ? i.e. It might be possible on a LAN - but it's not a good idea?

Comment: the link is the gist of it, but the other guy wanted, as I pointed out twice, a web-wide solution - which he didn't recieve of course - and I'm asking strictly local - that's why I'm suggesting arp since I know for a fact arp does work on server